# Showing that a collection of sets is a $\sigma$-algebra: either set or complement is countable

Tags: measure-theory

I wish to show that $$\mathcal{F} = \{A \subset \Omega: A \text{ countable or }A^c\text{ countable}\}$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra.

We have $\Omega^c = \emptyset$, so obviously $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$.

Suppose $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Assuming $A$ is countable, $(A^c)^c = A$ is countable, so $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$. If we assume $A^c$ is countable, $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$ follows trivially.

Now let $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$. I wish to show that either $A \cap B$ or $(A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$ is countable. **How would I start this part**? I am only looking for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the four cases:

$A$, $B$ countable.

$A$, $B^c$ countable.

$A^c$, $B$ countable.

$A^c$, $B^c$ countable.

What can be said of $A\cap B$ or $(A\cap B)^c$?